# Can I use an existing asbestos type flue on new gas fire installation

Tags: asbestos, flue

I'm planning on having a new wall hung inset gas fire. At the moment I'm using just the gas fire on a BBU, the boiler part has been disconnected for many years. The flue is an asbestos type, bricked in solid, in the chimney breast all the way up to the roof space, then asbestos pipe through the roof space and roof. Can the new gas fire be fitted using the existing flue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This *may* be jurisdiction dependent. Country/state/city?

Comment: The size/diameter/length of the pipe compared to what the new burner requires is important also.  It having asbestos is probably minor, except to buyers of the house.

Comment: Your local installers should know your local regulations. You'll have to call them to get estimates for the installation, so ask them about this, too.

Comment: Why do you want to use asbestos in the first place? It is banned in many countries for a reason.

Comment: @PMF  Sounds like it is already there, before it was banned.  OP just wondering if they can use it as is.